# Calculate EM-field or intensity field given radiation pattern

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

If I have a normalised radiation pattern (in dB) from an antenna, how would I go about getting the (far-field) intensity distribution?

My guess would be to convert the pattern to linear gain, multiply by the antenna's gain to unnormalise, then multiply by the power of the antenna to get the right units. I should now have a radiation pattern in Watts/(solid angle), so divide by $r^2$ to get Watts/m$^2$.

Edit: Specifically what I'm trying to do is to calculate the intensity iso-surface (for Radiation Hazard calculations), or find the surface where intensity is constant. I am given a radiation pattern of an antenna defined for every angle $\theta$ and $\phi$, as well as the power and gain of the antenna.

For example, if I have the radiation pattern in a file as

```
# Phi Theta Level
0 0 -5
0 1 -4.9
0 2 -4.8
...
1 0 -5
1 1 -4.9
1 1 -4.7
...
90 89 -0.01
90 90 0
90 91 -0.01
...
359 178 -4.7
359 179 -4.9
359 180 -5
```

then my pseudo-code would be

```
for (theta, phi) in (sphere surface)
    for r in (0 to max_r)
        intensity_field(r, theta, phi) = gain * power * 10^(pattern(theta, phi)) / r^2
        if intensity_field(r, theta, phi) < intensity_threshold then
            intensity_surface.append(r, theta, phi)
            break
```

and this would generate a set of [x, y, z] (after conversion to Cartesian) points which I could visualise as a point cloud in gnuplot etc.

Comment: Pretty much spot on.

Comment: So what's this [FEKO](https://www.feko.info/product-detail/overview-of-feko) program doing by running a full EM simulation when I want to generate the intensity field from the radiation pattern?

Edit: more info: [calculating radiation threshold isosurfaces](https://www.feko.info/applications/white-papers/radiation-hazard-analysis-with-feko/radiation-hazard-analysis-with-feko/view)

Comment: I'm not sure; you'd need to ask the programmers why. It is a little weird, I agree. The only thing I can think of is that the software has decided that your conditions don't match its definition of "farfield", which is a decision with a great deal of discretion / room for criterion variation.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Thanks for your help. I've added a more specific explanation of my problem. The thing is, the far field of these antennae are around 20 metres, whereas the radiation hazard zones are typically a few metres, making me think that I need to run a FMM simulation of the EM field using the design of the antenna, which is not feasible.